# Mail not receiving in webmail from gmail

Tags: gmail, plesk, webmail

I am using 1and1 server. It is hosted in plesk panel. My mails from webmail are getting receiving in spam and when I am sending a message from gmail it is not receiving to webmail. Where is the problem?

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 2):

Is your mail IP is blacklisted in spam databases ? Please check mail IP status at http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

And enable SPF and domain keys for your domain so that your mail will not receive in spam folder